# c++: variable to pointer, unexpected segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers

For the following code, everything is normal. However, if I define the variable as pointer, then the segmentation error comes out.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
struct foo
{
    double x;
    double y;
};
void func(const foo * pxy, foo * pda);
int main()
{
    foo a;
    foo b;
    cout << "Enter two numbers" << endl;
    while(cin >> a.x >> a.y)
    {
        func(&a,&b);
        cout << "press q to quit" << endl; 
    }
    cout << b.x << endl;
    cout << b.y << endl;

    return 0;
}

void func(const foo * pxy, foo * pda)
{
    pda->x = sqrt(pxy->x * pxy->x + pxy->y * pxy->y);
    pda->y = atan2(pxy->y, pxy->x);
}
```

If I change it like below (Other than the `main()`, rest of the code remains same), segmentation fault return.

```cpp
int main()
{
    foo* a;
    foo* b;
    cout << "Enter two numbers" << endl;
    while(cin >> a->x >> a->y)
    {
        func(a,b);
        cout << "press q to quit" << endl; 
    }
    cout << b->x << endl;
    cout << b->y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea what went wrong here.

Comment: Those pointers don’t point at anything.

Comment: To review: in the first example, where you reserve space to hold `foo` objects, you do not have a problem using that space. In the second example, where you do **not** reserve space to hold `foo` objects, you do have a problem using that (non-existent) space.

Comment: If you want to use a pointer, you have to give it a value (just like any other kind of variable). What was wrong with the first version anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version with pointers will work

```
int main()
{
    foo aa, bb;
    foo* a = &aa;
    foo* b = &bb;
    ...
}
```

The difference is that in this version the pointers are actually pointing at something. But I'm sure you'll agree there's no purpose to this code, it's better without the pointers.

Pointer variables are no different from other kinds of variables, if you want to use them, you have to give them values.

Comment: If one did want to heap allocate the foo for some reason, using pointers and new would be the way to go.